# How to generically execute a python function

Tags: python, function, databricks

I have a multitude of python functions stored in a repo. This repo is consumed in a databricks notebook. I want to be able to use the databricks API to call a generic notebook to execute any one of these functions. So far I am able to execute any generic function which has no parameters:

```
_temp = __import__(f'{froms}', globals(), locals(),[f'{imports}'] )
result = getattr(_temp, f'{imports}').main()
```

froms and imports come from the API call (e.g. from pandas import eval)

In databricks, the variable (in this instance params) is immediately parsed as a string, so if I add .main(params), it will interpret the params as the first paramater in the function.

How can I convert this string value (can take any form, I assume dict is the best option) into something which is parseable by the function.

Comment: I'm not entirely clear what you're asking. Are you saying that `params` can only be a string, but that you need to be able to pass arbitrary parameters in it? And given you seem to be calling third party modules, you need to support both positional and keyword parameters?

Comment: I will only be calling custom modules, I just gave the pandas as a (bad) example.  One of my functions may be like this:

def write_to_db(connection_string,  table_name)

I want to be able to support both positional and keyword arguments with the param. Param will be parsed from an API call so would be a string, so in this example param == ' connection_string = 'x', table = 'y' '

At the moment it will parse the whole paramater as a positional string, but I want it to parse as 2 parameters via keyword.

Comment: Do you care what format param is in? It would probably be easier to, say, make it a json string